# How can I give a default value for the StringField in WTForms

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have this class:

```
class New_video_form(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    genre = StringField('genre', validators=[DataRequired()])
    link = StringField('link', validators=[DataRequired()])
    image = StringField('Image', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = StringField('description', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

and i implemented this here:

```
<h1 style="color: white; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;">Editing the movie: {{ video.title }}</h1>
<form action="" method="POST" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin-top: 50px;">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.title(class="form-control", value="{{ video.title}}", placeholder="Title") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.genre(class="form-control", value="{{ video.genre }}", placeholder="Genre") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.link(class="form-control", value="{{ video.link }}", placeholder="Video Link") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.image(class="form-control", value="{{ video.image}}", placeholder="Image") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.description(class="form-control", value="{{ video.description }}", placeholder="Description") }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-lg">Send</button>
</form>
```

and this form is send from this route:

```
@controller.route('/edit/<int:id>/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def edit(id):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        form = New_video_form()
        video = Video.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        if request.method == "POST":
            video.title = form.title.data
            video.link = form.link.data
            video.image = form.image.data
            video.genre = form.genre.data
            video.description = form.description.data
            db.session.commit()
            #add a flash message
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            return render_template('edit.html',form=form, video=video)
    else: 
        return redirect(url_for('controller.admin'))
```

here i send the form and the data that will be used in the form as video, but when i put the data in the value field the form render {{ video.example }} not the value.
How can i do for the stringfield get the value from the {{ video.example }} and render the value?

ps: the h1 is rendering the right value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to display the form pre-filled, if the user comes to edit a video?

You could use [this API](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form.__init__) and pass the video object to the form when you initialise it, like so:

```py
video = Video.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
form = New_video_form(obj=video)
```

If you do that, you don't need to explicitly pass `value="{{video.title}}"` and so on for each of the fields.

Quick edit: just noticed that you are also missing `db.session.add(video)` before `db.session.commit()` — the changes won't be committed unless you add the updated object to the session.

Comment: What do you mean? Did my answer help you?

Comment: I have just one problem: all my inputs use the same code but one dont get the data, why this is happening?

Comment: Which input field isn't populated?

Comment: The genre input.

Comment: The code you pasted looks correct to me. The genre field in the form is the same as the other fields. Perhaps you have a typo somewhere else? What type is genre in the database? What's the definition of the Video model?